# Star Alliance - direct routes

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I don't know where I want to go, but I know how I want to get there! I'm looking for an efficient way to search for flights under the following criteria:

1. Operated by any Star Alliance partner
2. From a specified airport - in my case LHR, or set of airports such as London.
3. A direct flight

I'm trying to find inspiration for where to go for a short vacation, hence I don't yet know the destination. Using Star Alliance gets me miles towards maintaining my status on United. Using a chosen airport because that's where I live. Choosing a direct flight because I'm looking for simplicity.

Visiting each Star Alliance partner airline's web site in turn and finding their list of direct flights is presumably possible, but seems like a lot of work.

If I knew where I was going then there are plenty of decent search engines, but for this I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great website for this is www.flightconnections.com Select "Star Alliances" from Alliances and LHR as starting airport and you get a map of all direct Star Alliance destinations from LHR

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights) is good for this, you can select non stop flight in the filter and can select Star Alliance in the filter too. Example below.

[image: Google Flights example]

If you leave the destination blank you can see destinations where you can travel. There's an example below, if you zoom out to show the whole world theres a big scrollable list on the left hand side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of Google flights, but I think I need to know where I want to go! In your example you specify a destination. I have not been able to find a way to broaden this to "anywhere".

Comment: @djna You can leave the "where to" section blank and still filter by non stop and star alliance.

Comment: @djna To broaden your travels I'd recommend at least allowing one connection

Comment: @djna:  The best way to get what you want from the front page of Google Flights is to enter LHR and your dates into the search box, leaving the destination blank.  A world map will then pop up with possible destinations, and filters (including number of stops and airlines/alliances) will be in the upper left corner of the map.)

Comment: @djna updated answer to show any destination, try adding a connection too for more destinations.